# Advice on two implementations of async/await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I noticed that I am able to get the data in the following two ways (reference OPTION 1 and OPTION 2) and wanted to know if there are any implications/benefits in picking one over the other? I am using .NET 4.5.1 and am loading data from an on-premise SQL Server using async/await.

```
// ***** OPTION 1 *****

// Constructor
public SomeViewModel(IProjectService projectService)
{
    Task.Run(async () => await GetAllDataAsync());
}

// This method calls out all of the other local async/await methods to download the data
private async Task GetAllDataAsync()
{
    await GetProjectDataAsync();
    await GetAssignmentDataAsync();
    ... more await calls ...
}  

// A typical method call to get data from service
private async Task GetProjectDataAsync()
{
    var projects = await projectService.GetProjectsAsync();
    this.ProjectList = projects;
}

// ***** OPTION 2 *****

// Constructor
// I call Task.Run() for all of the methods that download data
public SomeViewModel()
{
    _service = service;
    Task.Run(async () => await this.GetProjectDataAsync());
    Task.Run(async () => await this.GetAssignmentDataAsync());
    ... more Task.Run() calls ...
} 

// A typical method call to get data from service
private async Task GetProjectDataAsync()
{
    var projects = await projectService.GetProjectsAsync();
    this.ProjectList = projects;
}
```

EDIT 1:

Here is an example of the async/await method from my repository:

```
public async Task<IList<Project>> GetProjectsAsync()
{
    using (Context ctx= new ProjectContext())
    {
        IEnumerable<Project> myProjects = ctx.Projects;
        return await myProjects.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:
I currently acquired the book, [Concurrency in C# Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449367569), by [Stephen Cleary](http://stephencleary.com/) and am looking for a suitable solution from the book in combination with the given advice here. Could anyone point me to certain section of the book that can assist me in my scenario, i.e. loading a lot of data from many tables that will be harnessed by an application?

EDIT 3:

// ***** OPTION 3 *****

```
// Constructor
public SomeViewModel()
{
    _service = service;
    DownloadData();
} 

// A normal method that awaits async methods
private void DownloadData()
{
    Task.Run(async () => await GetProjectDataAsync());
    Task.Run(async () => await GetAssignmentDataAsync());
    ... more await calls to async Task methods that call services that in turn have async Task methods
}
```

Comment: Why all the `Task.Run` calls? If the async methods are truly async, why do you need to run them in separate tasks? One thing you might want to consider is having a static async factory method which fetches all the data to start with, then calls a constructor with all the data ready. That way you can get the benefits of immutable types and asynchrony, which doesn't normally go well with the fact that constructors can't be async.

Comment: (1) is sequential, (2) is parallel; which one is likely to work better depends on what the underlying methods are doing, but if they are accessing a shared database, for instance, it is likely that they will end up contending for a shared resource, reducing the benefit of running them in parallel or even making performance worse due to increased overhead of task switching.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I'm currently looking at those alternatives and will report back, thanks!

Comment: @DanBryant - I did think that Option 2 was the better alternative. I am currently looking at the suggestions, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I doubt any of these are suitable for your needs. Since a constructor can't be `async` there is no way to wait until the task you start are complete. You could call `Task.Wait` but that would annihilate all the benefits derived from async and you'd need to deal with the resulting deadlock.

Right now the tasks you start run concurrently with the rest of the request processing. This is probably racy and not what you wanted. If this ever worked it was by accident.

Move that code out of the ctor to an ordinary method and use `await` all the way through.

Comment: I've added an OPTION 3.  As per your comment, "await all the way through", does my new code meet this or what did you have in mind, thanks.

Comment: You've just tried to cheat with option 3. Moving this stuff out into a new method changes nothing. DownloadData returns void so that callers cannot wait on it. This means that the race is still present. This also tells me that you do not understand how await works. You should research it because with your current level of understanding you are playing with fire.

Comment: You originally said "Move that code out of the ctor to an ordinary method..." which I believe void DownloadData() is or not?  The other parts might be wrong, but that in itself is an "ordinary method".  Also, OPTION 3 as you noted is wrong, but after some testing, these Tasks ARE running on separate cores. This I actually grabbed from someone else.

Comment: OK. You need to await all tasks that you produce eventually. Async void is not advisable since that amounts to just throwing the task of that async method away. So arrange the code so that there is no async void and everything is awaited eventually. This implies that there can be no await in a part of the call tree that is below a constructor call. Do this: `var x = new MyObj(); await x.Init();`. Something like that.